# Event driven binding / rebinding of v-model / v-bind?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm really struggling on how to implement a pattern inline with the "Vue philosophy".

Imagine a list of items that you'd like to edit. There are numerous examples of how to edit those items "inline". But I'd like to edit my items through the same, persistent form. So when you click a list item, the form input "rebinds" to clicked list item.

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/sopakid/3/edit?html,js,output which uses a method (updateRecord) to copy the form input (bound to editRecord), to the referenced li's data binding (messages[index]).

```
data: {
    messages: [
        { name: "Dale Cooper", message: "Black as midnight on a moonless night" },
        { name: "Shelly Johnson", message: "I've got one man too many in my life and I'm married to him." },
        { name: "Sheriff Truman", message: "Jelly donuts?"}
    ],
    editRecord: 
    { name: "", message: "" }
},

updateRecord: function(){
    var index = this.editRecord.index;
    this.messages[index].name = this.editRecord.name;
    this.messages[index].message = this.editRecord.message;
}
```

Looking for any insight as to how to better implement this pattern. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idiomatically, you don't really need any methods in this case. You can set the `editRecord` directly in the template. Additionally, if you set the `editRecord` to the selected `message`, then you don't even need an update button or a need to keep track of the index.

```
var app = new Vue({

    el: '#app',

    data: {
        editRecord:{ name: null, message: null },
        messages: [
            { name: "Dale Cooper", message: "Black as midnight on a moonless night" },
            { name: "Shelly Johnson", message: "I've got one man too many in my life and I'm married to him." },
            { name: "Sheriff Truman", message: "Jelly donuts?"}
        ]
    }
});
```

These are the changes I made to your template

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="messages">
    <ul>
      <li class="message" v-for="(message, index) in messages" @click="editRecord = message">
        <div class="message__name">
        {{message.name}}
        </div>
        <div class="message__body">
        {{message.message}}
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="edit-form" v-if="editRecord">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" v-model="editRecord.name">
    <label for="message">Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="6" v-model="editRecord.message"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is your [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/zayoqojuhe/edit?html,js,output) updated.

The result takes advantage of Vue's *reactivity* and as you edit in your form you can see the changes taking place in the list as well.

Some people may *like* the approach you've taken though, where the edits they make are not complete until they specify they are. A lot of this is a matter of taste.

I would warn against using `index` to track your selected record, however. If the list changes underneath you, the indexes change. Use an `id` property on your `messages`. If you go with the reactive approach though, you don't really need that.

Comment: first of all thank you. That's deceptively simple, and quite exciting. I was probably overthinking the problem. 

What's really novel and fun is how you establish a "link" between editRecord and message. I've learned a lot about Vue just from your simple example.

Comment: @monopineu it's largely about learning to think from a data-driven approach, or thinking about how the UI should be rendered based on the given state as opposed to imperatively doing things.